# can multipartfile send some information with image?

Tags: spring, react-native

I want send multipart/form-data to spring server with some information. but i dont know this is right way.

```
a.push({ name: 'file', filename: this.state.fileName, data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(this.state.uri), desc: 'triptriptrip'});
this.setState({
    images : a
  })
  });}

RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST',  'https://675c8a26.ngrok.io/appServer/postUpload/1', {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },this.state.images

        )
```

i expect spring server get 'desc' information but server cannot access to 'desc'. how to access that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `formdata`, use it like this.

```js
RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST','https://675c8a26.ngrok.io/appServer/postUpload/1',{
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  [
  { name: 'file', filename: this.state.fileName, data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(this.state.uri), desc: 'triptriptrip'},
  ]).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })  
});
```

Comment: thanks. i solved it by sending data separately. 'file' and 'description'. then spring can get data.